# What is the difference between "in-between" and "between"?

Tags: meaning, differences, prepositions, synonyms

Do *in-between* and *between* have different meanings?
What is the difference between *in-between* and *between*?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Well, *between* all by itself acts as a preposition, but *in between* functions as an adverb.

> *preposition*: I found myself caught between a rock and a hard place.
>
> *adverb*: There was a rock and a hard place, and there I was lying in between.

Comment: In the second example, _in_ seems associated to the verb, rather than to _between_, as in _the solution lies in a return to "traditional family values"._

Comment: @kiamlaluno: "in between" taken together is an adverb because it modifies the verb; your usage of "...lies in a return" uses *in* as a preposition.

Comment: I suspect most casual uses of _in between_ are wrong: "We were in between a rock and a hard place."

Comment: When does one use a hyphen, as in *in-between*? I've seen this used quite often, but is it incorrect?

Comment: In a compound modifier you would hyphenate it. "It was an in-between kind of thing." "Sally was an in-between girlfriend."

Comment: _Between_ can be an adverb, and _in between_ can function as a preposition.

Comment: @Færd - Could you move this to an answer, please?

Comment: @aparente001 Would be really relieved to have someone else do this stuff for me. Would you do the honor, please? :)

Comment: @Færd: Ya gotta put in your own work around here. ^_^

Comment: @Færd - No hurry.  Your comment's been sitting there since July.  I came here because I was proofreading a sentence that had "in between" as a preposition and was confused until I read your comment.  So I'm not the right person to write that answer.