# English language for in between

Tags: orthography

What would be the correct spelling for "in between" for the following:

> From the Sierra's to the sea and everywhere in between.

or

> From the Sierra's to the sea and everywhere inbetween.

Comment: If I've ever seen "inbetween" spelled that way (I don't recall that I have) I would have taken it to be a spelling error.,

Comment: 1. *Sierras*, not *Sierra's*.  2. But no - "*the Sierra*" is already plural.

Comment: See also [what-is-the-difference-between-in-between-and-between](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12407/what-is-the-difference-between-in-between-and-between) .  Sooner or later _inbetween_ will join the dictionary ranks of _alright_ and _already_.

Answer (score 1):

This is a matter of word choice, rather than correct spelling. The noun and adjective 'in-between' has these meanings:

> **in-beˈtween**, *n.* and *adj.*
>   **A.** *n.*
>      (a) An interval.  (b) A person who intervenes.
>   ....
>   **B.** *adj.*
>   Placed between.

["in-beˈtween, n. and adj.". OED Online. December 2015. Oxford University Press. http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/93227?redirectedFrom=in+between (accessed January 04, 2016).]

Your example doesn't seem to me to match any of those meanings. For your example, I would leave the "in" out altogether and use

> From the Sierras to the sea and everywhere between.

Answer (score 1):

Neither:

> From the Sierras to the sea and everywhere between.

The "*in*" is superfluous and [not needed in this context](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/between-vs-in-between/).